# Specifying parameters in tastypie-swagger

Tags: python, django, tastypie, swagger

I am using Tastypie as an API framework for Django for non-ORM data source. I have used [django-tastypie-swagger](https://github.com/concentricsky/django-tastypie-swagger). It has worked fine for everything but I haven't figured out how to display the parameters for get/post request for obj_get_list. Currently two default values are shown as shown below:

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The parameters are retrieved from filtering specified in the Meta of class inherited from Resource. There seems to be a small bug in django-tastypie-swagger as it doesn't recognize filters if it is specified as tuples. We need to specify filtering as lists. For e.g.

```
class VideoById(Resource):
    class Meta:
        filtering = {
            "filter1": ['exact', ],
            "filter2": ['exact', ],
        }
```

The above mentioned code works. But the following won't:

```
class VideoById(Resource):
    class Meta:
        filtering = {
                "filter1": ('exact', ),
                "filter2": ('exact', ),
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

Update the `django-tastypie-swagger` to *development version* or change the line 181 of `mapping.py`

From

```
if isinstance(field, list):
```

To

```
if isinstance(field, (list, tuple, set)):
```